# jQuery or PHP possible to show the nth/ index next to the item

Tags: php, jquery, html, list, class

**EDIT**:

I have 400 'inputs' on a page using the same class:

```
.oDiv
```

Is there a way to show on the page the `nth` position of that class (i.e its index) - so whether its the 1st, 2nd, 40th, 100th etc,

I have a series of classes on a page:

```
.oDiv
```

There are over 400 of these on the page - what I am doing is using:

```
$( '.oDiv:eq(6)' ).remove();
```

to remove some of these depending on a users selection.

What would help me in terms of coding, is to able to see on the .HTML page the `number` of each of the class - for error checking and debugging.

Example:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="oDiv" id="Mat"  name="spec[]" value="Mat 6"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="oDiv" id="Neo"  name="spec[]" value="Neo 7"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="oDiv" id="Prey"  name="spec[]" value="Prey 8"/>
```

Where 6 7 and 8 in the `value` shows they are the 6th, 7th and 8th in the list of `oDiv` classes.

Does that make sense and is this possible?

Comment: you are looking for length property or index() method or both. Now improve your question: what are you looking for?

Comment: I can't able to understand what's your problem.? can you add some more details ?

Comment: I have a list of classes and I want to show the number that relates to what position they are in the list.  So I can `see` on the HTML page wether they are 4th, 3rd, 20th etc.

Comment: You need to just get the value of the checkbox selected. Right ?

Comment: @Homer_J you aware that we still don't know HOW do you wish to get this value? Following an user interaction or what?

Comment: No, I don't want the value - I need to see what position the checkbox is in the list - in theory they should be consequtive starting from 0,1,2,3, up to 400 but it appears they are not - so to debug my code I need a way to show on the html page what number/ position they are in the list of classes.

Comment: @Homer_J see my answer for what you need.

Comment: @Homer_J you are looking for index()

Comment: Yes, index() would be correct - apologies for the lack of clarity.

Answer (score 2):

You can show onDocument load,

```
$.each($(".oDiv"), function() {
    $("#debug").append($(this).val() );
})
```

where we can have a

```
<div id="debug"></div>
```

to display the values of all your checkboxes.  For any removal of the checkboxes, just rerun the code to update the div.

Answer (score 1):

If the number is always the last character then use this:

```
$('input:checkbox').on('change', function(e) {
    var num = $(this).val().substr(-1);
    console.log(num);
});
```

Alternatively you can use [.index](http://api.jquery.com/index/) to get the position:

```
$('input:checkbox').on('change', function(e) {
    var num = $('input:checkbox').index($(this));
    console.log(num);
});
```

Note that [.index](http://api.jquery.com/index/) starts from 0, so the first item found will be 0, the second 1 etc.

```
$(function() {
    $('input:checkbox').each(function(i, e)) {
        var num = $('input:checkbox').index($(this));
        console.log($(this).val() + " is in position " + num);
    });
});
```

Comment: I think that is heading in the right direction - although this doesn't seem to work and I need it to show all positions, not just when I select one.

Comment: @Homer_J I've updated my answer to list out all positions, with the values so you can identify which one is in which position.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `.index(selector)`

Try this, I assume that you want to see its index when clicking.

```
$('.oDiv').click(function(){
  alert($('.oDiv').index(this));
});
```

Please read this to know more about [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

Comment: i guess it is `$(this).index()` or `$('.oDiv').index(this)`

Comment: Looking better - although, oddly it brings back `-1` regardless of what I click.

Comment: That's it but is there a way to show that index number next to each item as opposed to having to click on each to show it?

Comment: @Homer_J I've already updated my answer to show you what you need.

Comment: @Homer_J Next to what item.? Please Just provide a scenario.

Comment: Sorry, anywhere on the page will do but ideally next to the input.

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="oDiv" id="Mat"  name="spec[]" value="Mat 6"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="oDiv" id="Neo"  name="spec[]" value="Neo 7"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="oDiv" id="Prey"  name="spec[]" value="Prey 8"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.oDiv').each(function(index, element) {
            // index is a numerical increment of each element.
            // element is a javascript object of the "this" element.
            jQuery(element).after(jQuery(element).val() + '<br />');
            jQuery(element).on('change', function() {
                jQuery(this).remove();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```